C++ code stuck with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) during execution
I have a C++ function that gets stuck during execution and I get Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). I've tried debugging it, but I can't figure out why it's getting stuck.
Of course I searched for the error code meaning and it is "Access Violation" or "Segmentation Fault." but I still couldn't solve the problem
This function is part of a class I'm writing, but for now I've cleaned up the code and isolated the problematic part into a function called groupMinterms(). Here is the refined version of the code:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct GroupedData {
    std::vector<int> mintermsIncluded;
    std::vector<int> deletedArgs;
    int stage;
    int groupFromTop;
};

std::vector<GroupedData> groupedTerms = {
        {{0}, {}, 0, 0},
        {{1}, {}, 0, 1},
        {{2}, {}, 0, 1},
        {{4}, {}, 0, 1},
        {{8}, {}, 0, 1},
        {{3}, {}, 0, 2},
        {{5}, {}, 0, 2},
        {{6}, {}, 0, 2},
        {{9}, {}, 0, 2},
        {{7}, {}, 0, 3}
}; //initializing the vector only for testing purposes

bool isPowerOfTwo(int num) {
    return num > 0 && (num & (num - 1)) == 0;
}

void groupMinterms() {
    int stage = 1;
    int groupFromTop = 0;
    int startIndex;
    int endIndexHolder = 0;
    std::vector<int> combinedMinterms;
    std::vector<int> deletedArgs;

    while (true) {
        startIndex = endIndexHolder;
        endIndexHolder = groupedTerms.size();
        bool anyAdded = false;

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndexHolder; i++) {
            const auto& upperdata = groupedTerms[i];

            for (int j = i + 1; j < endIndexHolder; j++) {
                const auto& lowerdata = groupedTerms[j];

                if (upperdata.stage == lowerdata.stage && upperdata.groupFromTop + 1 == lowerdata.groupFromTop && isPowerOfTwo(lowerdata.mintermsIncluded[0] - upperdata.mintermsIncluded[0])) {

                    combinedMinterms.clear();
                    combinedMinterms.insert(combinedMinterms.end(), upperdata.mintermsIncluded.begin(), upperdata.mintermsIncluded.end());
                    combinedMinterms.insert(combinedMinterms.end(), lowerdata.mintermsIncluded.begin(), lowerdata.mintermsIncluded.end());

                    deletedArgs.clear();
                    deletedArgs.insert(deletedArgs.end(), upperdata.deletedArgs.begin(), upperdata.deletedArgs.end());
                    deletedArgs.push_back(lowerdata.mintermsIncluded[0] - upperdata.mintermsIncluded[0]);

                    groupedTerms.push_back({ combinedMinterms, deletedArgs, stage, groupFromTop });
                    anyAdded = true;
                }
            }
            groupFromTop++;
        }

        if (!anyAdded)
            break;

        stage++;
    }
}

int main() {
    groupMinterms();

    // Print the contents of groupedTerms for verification, but because of the problem, it
    //  never reaches here:
    for (const auto& data : groupedTerms) {
        std::cout << "stage: " << data.stage << "| groupFromTop: " << data.groupFromTop;
        std::cout << " | Minterms Included:";
        for (const auto& minterm : data.mintermsIncluded) {
            std::cout << " " << minterm;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

The code uses a struct GroupedData to hold grouped minterms and some related information. The groupMinterms() function is where the issue occurs. It seems to run partially and then stops with the exit code mentioned above.
How can I identify why it's getting stuck?

Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A for technical questions, not a debugging service. 0xC0000005 is an Access Violation. You are trying to access memory you are not allowed to access. You need to debug your code to find out which line specifically is accessing memory incorrectly.

Run your code in a debugger, get a stack trace, look at the variables of the last stack frame that contained your code.

const auto& upperdata = groupedTerms[i]; will become dangling because of groupedTerms.push_back({ combinedMinterms, deletedArgs, stage, groupFromTop });

Thanks! I did some research and I found out the problem and now at least I know what the problem is! Now, do you have any suggestion to how to solve this problem?

To solve this particular problem is easy. Just change to:
const auto upperdata = groupedTerms[i]; i.e. make a copy instead of a reference.
